# Advantage of 2-way merge sort against n-way

Tags: sorting, merging

It's known 2-way Merge sort takes N*logN time.

I wonder, what would be the running time if we split an array **of the size** N into N subarrays and then do the same thing as we would do for 2-way Merge?

Comment: selecting the smallest of k (unsorted) elements takes O(k), if you split into 3 arrays you need 2 compares each step in the merge

Comment: @ratchetfreak, please have a look at my update.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the recurrence will be:

[image]

where `f(n)` is the merge function.

Of course in 2-way merge sort we can do this in linear time, hence `f(n)=O(n)` for the `k=2` case. But in general, the best time this can be done is `O(nlogk)`, using [Priority Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055909/algorithm-for-n-way-merge).

Now, according to the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) you can solve this recurrence and see that `T(n)=O(n log n).`

So in asymptotic notation it looks like both k-way and the original merge-sort are equal. however note that in practice, implementing the original merge-sort is simpler and might require less effort to implement and maintain.

Comment: what's this formula, is this from Master method?